# Python data type behaving some different

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am finding out difference between data types in python . I am little bit confuse why type of demo2 is giving list instead of tuple . Can anyone tell me why it is printing type list instead of tuple ?

**Code**

```
demo1 = ()
print ("demo1 {}".format(type(demo1)))

demo2 = ([])
print ("demo2 {}".format(type(demo2)))

demo3 = ([],[])
print ("demo3 {}".format(type(demo3)))
```

**Output**

```
demo1 <type 'tuple'>
demo2 <type 'list'>
demo3 <type 'tuple'>
```

Comment: `demo2 = ([])` should be `demo2 = ([],)` if you want a tuple too

Comment: ok but syntax of tuple is  tuple  = () ?@PRMoureu

Comment: you're right, but you must add a comma when you declare a single element in a tuple

Comment: ok it means at least  one comma is needed correct ?

Comment: [], is equal to ([],) if I am not wrong and ([],) is a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `() small brackets` are block enclosing brackets but eventually this represents tuple too in `python`. whenever we declare a tuple into python we need to comma separate 2 values or assign `()` (small opening and closing brackets, this will create an empty tuple).

So in your `demo3` you made a `list` and enclosed with brackets that means your `demo3` have a `list vector`. If you provide `comma` after `[]` just like `([], )` it will make a tuple of `lists`.

Below are some enhanced examples: -
[image]

Answer (score 2):

To create an empty tuple, use `tuple()`. It will *print* as `()`, but that's not how you create an empty tuple. As minimum, a tuple must contain one item. So you need to create it as `([],)`.

Your code `([])` is the same as `[]`, the parenthesis in this case act as *continuation characters*` and not an empty tuple.

> Expressions in parentheses, square brackets or curly braces can be
>   split over more than one physical line without using backslashes.

*See [the documentation on lexical analysis](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#implicit-line-joining) for more details.*

You can also verify this at the interpreter:

```
>>> ([]) == []
True
```